# BigQuery PARSE_PACKED_IP does not work

Tags: google-bigquery

When I try to use the Google's bigquery I get an error for the parse_packed_ip function:

SELECT PARSE_PACKED_IP ('3031:3233:3435:3637:3839:4041:4243:4445');

However FORMAT_PACKET_IP function works okay.  Anyone has filed a bug report with Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does seem to be a bug -- as a workaround, try casting the result to a `STRING`. For instance,

```
SELECT STRING(PARSE_PACKED_IP('3031:3233:3435:3637:3839:4041:4243:4445'));
```

works for me.

Comment: And, as a bonus, this should be fixed in BQ in the not-too-distant future.